# Newly created users not seeing tables they've been granted privs on in clients

Tags: mysql, privileges

This is driving me a bit crazy.
I've created 2 new users with identical privs on specific tables on specific databases; e.g. SELECT on d1.table1 & SELECT,UPDATE on db1.table2 and SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE on db2.table1 and SELECT on db2.table1 - you get the idea. All GRANTS were done as root and a FLUSH PRIVILEGES issued after the fact.
The users are of the form 'name'@'192.168.1.%'. All the entries for the users look ok in the user,db,and table_privs tables. SHOW GRANTS shows all the GRANTed privs.

The problem is, that when you connect as either of these users, one database on which table privs has been granted is not visible with a SHOW DATABASES, and for the other databases which are, only some tables are visible on which privileges have been granted. There seems to be no pattern to the denial of visibility in terms of the which tables have which grants.

I have absolutely no idea what's going on here. I've done quite a bit of reading in forums and I have a reasonable grasp of the MySQL privilege system, but this has me stumped. Why ON EARTH should some databases be not seen by the client or only some tables or none at all (for the databases that are)?

T.I.A,

GAM

Comment: For one user that does not work: can you add `select user()`, `show grants` and describe what statement does not show the expected result? If you do not want to reveal private information, create a new user, a new database and new tables (and you can then add the grants statements you used too to make it reproducable). "all entries for the users look ok" is a bit too vague to tell you what's wrong - since very likely at least one entry is actually not ok (or is missing), and it's much easier for you to tell us what you have/did *exactly*, then for us to list everything that could be wrong.

Comment: Hi - I tried to put the output in a comment here, but it was too long by a significant amount. Can I only respond in the comments now? Sorry - bit of a Stack Exchange newbie and can only see the "Answer Your Question" button available - which I don't want to do. Do I put output on PasteBin or something like that?

Comment: You can (and are supposed to) edit your question (the small "edit" on the left side under your question/above the comments).

Comment: Ok - [here](https://pastebin.com/N4cLJ2U4) is what was required put on PasteBin. This has been solved by virtue of my granting SELECT access on all tables on all databases concerned, but I would still like to understand why the most restrictive (desired) permissions are not working.

Comment: Your grants look looks fine and should work as you expected it. Hard to say what is going wrong. You may want to test it on a backup server, add this user first, test if it works, then add other users and check if there might be a conflict somewhere (although it might depend on the order, so it might not be reproducable this way). Sorry that I am out of ideas.

Comment: Yes - I'll test on my test server. This is not the first time this has happened on this server & warrants further investigation. Thanks for your input @Solarflare.